# I'm having trouble with testing checking a rabbitmq queue after a POST request with mocha and supertest

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I'm a little new with mocha and supertest. Right now I'm testing checking a RabbitMQ queue after i make a post request which sends the said message to a exchange. right now I have this code:

```
var app= null;
//function to bind the queue to the exchange
function bindQueue(callback){
  console.log('BIND STARTED');  
  conn.addListener('ready', function() {
    var queueName = 'testQueue';
    var queueOptions = {durable : false, autoDelete: true};
    conn.queue(queueName,queueOptions,function(queue) {
      queue.bind('exchange', '#');
      queue.subscribe({ack: true},callback.bind(null,queue));  
    });
  });  
}


describe('Testing publish messages to the worker after change of data(Add,Update,Delete)', function() {
  app = 'http://'+config.auth.basic.username+':'+config.auth.basic.password+'@'+ config.ifc + ':' + config.port;

  it("should receive a message after adding data",function(done){  
    //queue binding
    bindQueue(function (queue,message){
      console.log('RECIEVED MESSAGE');
      if(message.response._id == 2){
        queue.shift(true,false); //take it off  from the queue 
        console.log('IS RIGHT');    
      } else {
          throw "not the right message";
      }
      done();
    });

    supertest(app)
      .post(config.apiPrefix+'/\$test_1/user/2')
      .send({
        'role': ['Student'],
        'suffix': '',
        'firstname': 'Peter',
        'lastname': 'Doe',
        'dateOfBirth': '1980-03-30',
        'gender':'Male',
         'email': 'petter@hgmail.com',
         'createDate': '2014-10-25',
         'status': 'active'
      })
      .expect(200)
      .end();      
  });
  it("should receive a message after updating data",function(done){  
      //queue binding
    bindQueue(function (queue,message){
      if(message.response._id == 2){
        console.log('MESAGE RECIEVED 2');
        queue.shift(true,false); //take it off  from the queue 
        console.log('IS RIGHT');    
      } else {
          throw "not the right message";
      }
      done();
    });
    supertest(app)
      .put(config.apiPrefix+'/\$test_1/user/2')
      .send({
          'middleinitial':'M'
      })
      .expect(200)
      .end();
    });
});
```

When i run a single test(e.g. only the post one), all goes right, the queue callback is called and the message id is verified.
The problem starts when i try to make more than one test like the code I have above. when I run the test it shows the following error:

```
Testing publish messages to the worker after change of data(Add,Update,Delete)
BIND STARTED
RECIEVED MESSAGE
IS RIGHT
    ✓ should receive a message after adding data (266ms)
BIND STARTED
    1) should receive a message after updating data
RECIEVED MESSAGE
IS RIGHT
    2) should receive a message after adding data


  1 passing (453ms)
  2 failing

  1) Testing publish messages to the worker after change of data(Add,Update,Delete) should receive a message after updating data:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
      at _stream_readable.js:908:16

  2) Testing publish messages to the worker after change of data(Add,Update,Delete) should receive a message after adding data:
     Error: done() called multiple times
      at Suite.<anonymous> (test/7-test-message-publish.js:36:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/7-test-message-publish.js:33:1)
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at node.js:814:3
```

I've tried multiple things but I'm running out of options. Does anyone knows what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the equivalent of a memory leak... in this case, it's really a consumer leak. You're creating consumers and never unsubscribing them.

Every time you call `bindQueue(function(){....})` you are adding another consumer to the message queue. But you are never unbinding or removing the listener from the queue.

If you run a test once, it works because there is only 1 consumer getting messages. But if you run 2 tests, it fails because you added a total of 2 consumers and there is no guarantee of which consumer receives the message that was sent. You're probably getting the message sent to an old consumer, which ends up trying to call code that no longer works because that test was already torn down.

You should unsubscribe from the queue, after each test completes.

---

update from comments:

it looks like your using the `postwait/node-amqp` library, right? to unsubscribe a single consumer, you have to do this:

```js
connection.queue('foo', function(queue) {

var ctag;

queue
    .subscribe(function(msg) {...})
    .addCallback(function(ok) { 
      ctag = ok.consumerTag; 
    });

// ... and in some other callback
  queue.unsubscribe(ctag);
});
```

note the `addCallback` and the `ctag` that is being stored, so you can unsubscribe that specific consumer, later.

---

p.s. the general rabbitmq community recommends not using this particular library, as it has a history of leaking channels. they may have fixed this by now... but most node / rabbitmq is done with amqplib (amqp.node) or bramqp at this point.

Comment: i did  queue.unbind() in the end of the message callback before done() and i get the following error:  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
      at _stream_readable.js:908:16
Is that not how you unbind a queue?